# Is it possible to create 3d panoramic video

Tags: 3d-view, video, vr

While I understand that it is possible to create panormaic videos for Youtube, is there any way to make it 3d. I was pondering the idea that I could render it out with 2 cameras and stitch it together using another application, but I'm curious to see if there was some way to do it all natively in Blender?

Answer (score 3):

Alright nevermind I'm just dumb. If for some reason you searched this up and was wondering the same thing. Output settings > stereoscopic then go to Camera properties > type:panoramic and set panoramic type to equirectangular. This has to be in cycles. Or if you want it in video form https://youtu.be/OMGxpJKmLn0.